# how to add another value to the existing JSON object in ruby on rails and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In the `model` i have like,

```
  def question_hash_string
    @question_hash_string || '{}'
  end

  def question_hash
    ActiveSupport::JSON.decode question_hash_string
  end
```

In the `Javascript`,

```
var question_hash_element = document.getElementById('enr_rds_batch_update_question_hash_string');
var question_hash = JSON.parse(question_hash_element.value);

question_hash[batch_question_id] = (batch_answer_id || batch_rdsap_answer || batch_answer_checkbox);
question_hash_element.value = JSON.stringify(question_hash);
```

It would give the values like `"{"16":"3","28":false}"`

I want to add another value with the answer like the following,

```
question_hash[batch_question_id] = ((batch_answer_id || batch_rdsap_answer || batch_answer_checkbox) && (build_id));
```

`"{"16":"3","28":false:"2", "3":"55":"54"}"` and so on. I need to add another column with the existing record with ':'.

Comment: As far as I know, javascript does not allow data structures like `{a:b:c}`. Any plain object must be in the form of `{key:value}`. Could you explain the nature of "a", "b", and "c" in your code?

Comment: really not clear what you want and 1/2 the code shown doesn't make sense

Comment: already my task has some JSON object that has values like {"a":"b"} and i want to add the c value with that values. Where a is a question id and b is a answer id and i want to add c value(if c has value)

Comment: @charlietfl hi... its a task to finish the incomplete task. I am ready to explain in detail.

Comment: Does `{questionId:16,answerId:3,answerValue:'anything'}` fits with your idea?

Comment: {questionId:16, answerId:3, buildId:5} where buildId is the value of some class.... so it should be some value or null

Comment: Please make an effort to explain better. Does this structure finally suits your needs?

Comment: @wared yes it is. Thanks.. sorry for made that confused..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22744/discussion-between-wared-and-vinay)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a key/value pair to a javascript object :

```
var question_hash = { question_id:2, answer_id:3 };
question_hash.build_id = 6;
```

Comment: is it possible to store just the values? because loads of multiple times of values gonna into be that question_hash

Comment: Use an array instead of an object : `var q = [2,3,6]`. Then `q[0]` stands for `question_id`, `q[1]` stands for `answer_id`, and so on...

Comment: so, is it possible to create an array like {[2,3,4], [5,7,8]} like this?

Comment: Remember `{key:value}`. However, I guess you are trying to do something like this : `[[2,3,4],[5,7,8]]`. I think it's not the right place to learn javascript. You should look for some tutorials to get the basics.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a new element in the JabvaScript code.

```
function doSomething(value) {
   var jsonValues = getParameters();

   jsonValues.value3 = value; //Here you add a new value in your json
}

//Example of function to generate json
function getParameters() {

    return {
        value: 'a',
        value1: 'b',
        value2: 'c'
    };
}
```